# Is it possible to colorize same border from different zones?

Tags: html, css, frontend

There's a similar question here in this link
[CSS Change color of half of a border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75046094/css-change-color-of-half-of-a-border)
but it uses gradient. I have solid colors.

I have a `div` tag with `300x300` width and height.

I want to give border color similar to this picture:

[image]

I have no Idea how can I create such border color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.container {
height: 300px;
width: 300px;
  background: linear-gradient(
    50deg,
    yellow 0%,
    yellow 50%,
    navy 50%,
    navy 100%
  );
padding: 5px;
border-radius: 6px;
}

.container > div { background: #fff; height: 300px; width: 300px;border-radius: 6px; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div>text inside container</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you so much. I wounder, if it is possible to make color contacting points little smoother? is it possible? like where the navy and yellow contacts each other